# OneDrive REST API for Thumbnails Returns Non-Existent URL

Tags: onedrive

We are currently trying to get the thumbnails for user's files by calling [REST API for DriveItem Thumbnails](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_list_thumbnails?view=odsp-graph-online). The API that we are using to get the thumbnail is:

```
https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}/thumbnails
```

For most of the files, the URL returned in the response gives the valid thumbnail.

For some files (e.g. file with random extension as '.abcd'), we get  URL in the response which when called results in **404 Not Found**.

Does anybody have the solution for this?
Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks a ton in advance.

Comment: This is most likely due to the service not knowing how to generate a thumbnail for the file type. What behaviour would you like to see for this scenario?

Comment: Thank you Brand for your reply.

Yes, that is exactly my point. If service is unable to generate a thumbnail for some file, it should return no value for "thumbnails" attribute in the response JSON (similar to the way it is done for .mp3 files).

The problem is it returns thumbnail URL (which does not exist) and when we call the URL from our application we get 404 error.

Comment: I see what you're getting at - thanks for the clarification Yogesh.